# Dynamically reload django-filter (Model)ChoiceFilters drop-down contents

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using a django-filter to present a drop-down list (using ModelChoiceFilter).  I'm wanting to re-load the drop down contents dynamically when the user selects a certain option (that is stored in the session; not shown in the code below).  Unfortunately I'm not having any luck in achieving this.  I seem to be unable to address the class (as opposed to the instance) variable that defines the drop-down list.  This is what I have so far (AnotherModel contains a ForeignKey relationship to MyModel)

(filter.py)

```
import django_filters

class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet)

    drop_down = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(filter1)) 

    i = 3 # A non-filter class variable

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.drop_down = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(filter2))
        self.i = 5

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        # Throws AttributeError; type object 'MyFilter' has no attribute 'drop_down'
        <edit: printing drop-down throws the error; assigning to it works>
        print cls.drop_down
        cls.drop_down = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(filter2))
        cls.i=4 # Works fine
```

(views.py)

```
from project.filters import MyFilter
def my_filter(request):

    print MyFilter.i   # prints 3

    # Throws AttributeError; type object 'MyFilter' has no attribute 'drop_down'
    print MyFilter.drop_down    

    f =MyFilter(request.GET,
                queryset = AnotherModel.objects.filter(xyz))

    print MyFilter.i    # prints 3
    print f.i           # prints 5 (as expected)

    # Renders a drop-down populated with the values from filter1, not filter2 
    return render(request,'template.html', {'filter' : f})
```

I had initially hoped the re-assigning the instance of drop_down would work, but since that didn't I started looking at the class variable.  However it's unclear to me why I'm unable to access the class variable; in both cases where its addressed directly through MyFilter.drop_down and through the @classmethod function it throws an AttributeError, that the type object 'MyFilter' has no attribute 'drop_down'.  As shown above I can access the class variable i as expcted.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?  Or is there another approach that can be recommended, or should I give up on the django-filter and use the standard django filters and solve the problem as described here: [http://www.ilian.io/django-forms-choicefield-with-dynamic-values/]?

[EDIT]
@ Alex Morozov
Yes, my goal is to change the content of the drop down at runtime.  In this case, this would involve a new queryset being assigned to the ModelChoiceFilter.  Something like this

```
__init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.session = kwargs.pop('session', None)
    super(MyFilter,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.drop_down = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset = MyModel.my_custom_manager.my_customer_filter_that_uses_session(self.session))
```

I know that this example simply initializes the instance's copy of drop_down (and thus does not have the desired effect), but hopefully the intent is clear?

Comment: Just a clarification: you want your `drop_down` queryset to be dynamically assigned based on the value of the session variable, right? Or some other queryset?

Comment: Yes, please see edit above.